# Why does this use of size() in min() function in C++ give an error?

Tags: c++, size, min

```
    int var = 20;
    vector<string> A{"anything here", "random words"};
    for(int i = 0;i<A.size();i++)
        m=min(var,A[i].size());  

    // rest of the code here
    //assume proper headers were included
```

Line 4 gives an error: no matching function for call to 'min(int&,std::__cxx11::basic_string::size_type)'

Comment: Concerning your title: Actually, it's not the `size()` what causes the problem but the fact that you pass arguments of two different types to `std::min()`. According to its [definition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min), it can be deduced properly only for two equal argument types. The other option would be to make the type of `min` explicit, e.g. `min<size_t>(var, A[i].size())` or `min<int>(var, A[i].size())`. Though, keep in mind what has been told about `size_t` vs. `int`...

Comment: Consider using an iterator for loop for code like this. So `for (const auto& s : A) m = min(var, s.size());`. And also consider keeping a little more whitespace in your code, to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

You try to compare different types. Size yields a `size_t` type (wich usually is a `unsigned long long`). You can simply change the type of `var`:

```
string::size_type var = 20;
```

should do the trick.

Same for `i` in the for loop:

```
for (string::size_type i = 0; i < A.size(); i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

Better code like this

```
size_t var = 20;
vector<string> A{"anything here", "random words"};
for (size_t i = 0; i < A.size(); i++)
    m = min(var, A[i].size());
```

`var` and `i` should be type `size_t` since they are being compared with `A.size()` which has type `size_t`. Presumably `m` should be too.

And, to answer the question, `std::min` (and `std::max`) require the same type for both arguments.